# Where can I find meek servers?

Tags: bridge, pluggable-transports, meek

There is a maintained list of meek bridges like the others one ?

if not where can I find meek servers ?

Answer (score 2):

The meek servers are distributed with Tor Browser.

The point of meek is to be difficult to censor not because the bridges are hard to find but because they're hard to distinguish from other traffic.

You might have luck requesting meek bridges from [BridgeDB](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges#FindingMore) but it's not the most common transport, since it's only effective if there are other types of traffic which also use the same service which you can blend in to.

The large providers which provide suitable services are already covered by the defaults in Tor Browser. It may be that others run and distribute them manually and you could similarly set up your own meek bridge to use.

Answer (score 1):

All bridge servers included with the Tor Browser Bundle, including for obfs3, obfs4, fte, and meek, appear to be listed in `extension-overrides.js`, in the Linux version:

```
tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/preferences/extension-overrides.js
```

The current 2 meek servers are given as:

```
meek 0.0.2.0:2 B9E7141C594AF25699E0079C1F0146F409495296 url=https://d2cly7j4zqgua7.cloudfront.net/ front=a0.awsstatic.com
meek 0.0.2.0:3 97700DFE9F483596DDA6264C4D7DF7641E1E39CE url=https://meek.azureedge.net/ front=ajax.aspnetcdn.com
```

To manually add them to a `torrc` file, you'd write:

```
UseBridges 1
Bridge meek 0.0.2.0:2 url=<url> front=<front>
Bridge meek 0.0.2.0:3 url=<url> front=<front>
ClientTransportPlugin meek exec /path/to/meek-client
```

Since meek servers are not actually Tor bridges, the bridge address `0.0.2.0:port` is ignored and can be anything.